# SQLAlchemy - Different ways of updating

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm using python 3, SQLAlchemy and MySQL.

Suppose I reflect an existent table from my database with:

```
Clients = Table('tbl_clients', Base.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

Then I query it with this:

```
first_row = session.query(Clients).first()
```

and get a row with id 1. I know I can update like this:

```
Clients.update().where(Clients.c.id == 1).values(name='First client')
```

My question is: can I make the same update using the **first_row** object in some way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`First_row.[name of column] = new_value`

Then commit changes.

Comment: The question uses a `Table`, not a mapped class. This will not work, or at least did not use to.